# Reading a large CSV file in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, anaconda

I am trying to read a large CSV file(about 650 megabytes) and converting it to a numpy array and using pandas to read the file, and then print the numpy array.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None)
csv  = np.array(csv)
print(csv)
```

Running this code crashed my computer the last time I tried it. Any suggestions how to run it without crashing my computer?

Here are my laptop specs:

CPU: Intel Core i7 6500U

RAM: 12 GB LPDDR4

GPU: GeForce 940MX


EDIT: Nevermind, all I had to do is add `low_memory = false` when loading the CSV file.

Comment: Why did your computer crash (out of memory/cpu/?)

Comment: Also if the `pd.read_csv` works successfully... what are you trying to do by using `np.array` on it? pandas uses numpy underneath - it just has a higher level API to things, so you've already got numpy array(s)...

Comment: I don't know why it crashed my computer. It just froze, and I had to force restart it. Also thanks for telling me that pandas uses numpy. One less line of code...

Comment: Oh problem fixed. I just had to add low memory = false when I am loading the file, and I am converting it to a numpy array because when I imported it, and printed it, it is in a format that I don't want.

Comment: `np.array(df)` is equal to `df.values`